# IOS/Objective-C:Animation of Multiple CGAffineTransformations

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransformscale

I am trying to perform an animation that does three things at once: translates, rotates and changes the size of an image.

I can do two at once, translate and size.  However, when I add in rotation at the end of the following code, it is ignored.  And if I place it at the beginning of the code, the size change is ignored.  I've read that you can do a composite transition with view.transform, however, I have not been able to get that to work.

Here is my current code:

```
CGPoint destPoint = CGPointMake(-100,-50);
 float radians =[self Degrees2Radians:-35];
 [UIView animateWithDuration:2 
                 animations:^{
                     //TRANSLATE
                     self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.imageView.center.x + destPoint.x, self.imageView.center.y + destPoint.y);

                     //ROTATE
                      self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);

                  //SCALE

                     self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.2, 0.2); // here the final size will be 20%

                 }
                 completion:nil
 ];
```

}

Can anyone recommend way to get all three things to occur simultaneously.

Here is some code for swift that uses the transform property of the view, but I have not been able to find the equivalent in Objective-C.

```
view.transform= CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
view.transform = view.transform.rotated(by angle: CGFloat(45 * M_PI / 180))
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CGAffineTransformRotate` function on the existing transform to apply a rotation. You can also use `CGAffineTransformTranslate` and `CGAffineTransformScale` to apply translation and scaling. Please note that, order of the operations matter.

For example if you have an existing transform `myTransform` you can rotate it like:

`myTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(myTransform, M_PI / 2);`

The operation **does not affect** the input variable, instead, it returns a new transform so make sure you use the return value of the function. That's why I started the line with `myTransform = ...`.

More information is available at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform-rb5?language=objc.

Comment: How do you get the existing transform.  Can you suggest code in Obj-c?

Comment: @user6631314 sure, I've updated my answer. hope it helps.

Comment: That did the job!  Thanks.